# How to deal with an empty list when finding last elements in a list of lists in Prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, predicate, empty-list

I have a list of lists in Prolog. I've written a predicate that can find the last elements given a list such as this one:

```
L = [[a,b],[c,d,e],[f,g]]
```

This is the code, where the last_in_list/2 predicate just finds the last element in a simple list:

```
last_in_lol([], []).
last_in_lol([H|T], [X|Y]) :- last_in_list(X, H), append([],[X],L), last_in_lol(T, Y).
```

This seems to work just fine, outputting:

```
last_in_lol(L, F).
F = [b,e,g]
```

However, this fails when I give it a list which contains an empty list, like the following:

```
L = [[], [p,q,r], [s,t]]
```

I'm not sure how to go about augmenting my original predicate to handle this type of scenario. At the moment, this returns as False:

```
last_in_lol(L, F).
False.
```

I'd like it to return the list:

```
F = [r,t]
```

Comment: Looks like you can remove: `append([],[X],L)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use head-and-tail notation:

```
last_in_lol([], []).
last_in_lol([[]|R], Y) :-
    last_in_lol(R, Y).
last_in_lol([[H|T]|R], [Last|Y]) :-
    last_elem([H|T], Last),
    last_in_lol(R, Y).

last_elem([H|T], Elem) :-
    last_elem_(T, H, Elem).

last_elem_([], Elem, Elem).
last_elem_([H|T], _, Elem) :-
    last_elem_(T, H, Elem).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- L = [[a,b],[c,d,e],[f,g]], last_in_lol(L, F).
L = [[a, b], [c, d, e], [f, g]],
F = [b, e, g].

?- L = [[], [p,q,r], [s,t]], last_in_lol(L, F).
L = [[], [p, q, r], [s, t]],
F = [r, t].
```